popen is successful, but can't get data by fgets/fread
the cmd is printf "GET /xml?method=gw.log.download&id=4&pass=voip HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 80
when i execute it on console, the result is
/mnt/rwfs/var/run # printf "GET /xml?method=gw.log.download&id=4&pass=voip HTTP/
1.1\r\n\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 80
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
var/log/usb.log
var/log/version
var/log/versions/
var/log/versions/initsys
var/log/warning.log
var/tmp/message.log
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2024 06:52:18 GMT
Server:
X-Frame-Options:DENY
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Expires:-1
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Strict-Transport-Securit: max-age = 16070400
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (null)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 148

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<config  method="gw.log.download">
<item id="4" value="t9.tar.gz" />
</config>
</rsp>


my code is to retrieve the value corresponding to value, which in this case is "t9.tar.gz".
static void request_download_log(char *tar_file_name)
{
    char sys_cmd[128] = {0};
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char buff[128] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;
    char *q = NULL;

    tar_file_name[0] = 0;

    sprintf(sys_cmd, "printf \"GET /xml?method=gw.log.download&id=4&pass=%s HTTP/1.1\\r\\n\\r\\n\" | nc 127.0.0.1 80  2>&1", "voip");

    fp = popen(sys_cmd, "r");

    if (NULL != fp) {
        //while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL) {
        while(fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff) - 1, fp) > 0) {
            if ((p = strstr(buff, "value=\"")) != NULL) {
                p += strlen("value=\"");
                q = p;
                while (*q != '"') {
                    q++;
                }
                *q = 0;

                strcpy(tar_file_name, p);
                break;
            }
        }
        pclose(fp);
    }

    debug_log(eLOG_COMP_FUNCTION, 4, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "%s:%s", __FUNCTION__, tar_file_name);
}

however, there is approximately a 50% chance that fgets or fread will return NULL directly, resulting in my inability to obtain the result.
Why ? ? ?

OT: You need to "reset" the contents of buff before each call to fread. Or save the value that fread returns to know where to put the string null-terminator.

I understand that because popen is non-blocking, there is a probability that before fgets is called, my command has not finished executing

While fgets reads a full line, fread will not care about line structure. It could well happen that your search string "value=\"" and/or the following value are cut off at the end of the buffer. You need to take care about that and keep a few characters at the end of the current chunk when you read the next chunk.

It might not be a good idea to mix the standard error output with the standard output from nc.

Don't try to do HTTP client processing with basic tools not designed to handle the complex protocols and data structures in use.  Use something like libcurl and an actual XML parser.  HTTP is complex and completely unsuited to block reads and parsing with strstr().  XML is no better

fread() doesn't add a null terminator to buff, so you can't use strXXX functions on it.

Where is the tar output coming from? nc shouldn't print anything before the HTTP/1.0 200 OK response line.
